# VB.NET flowlayoutpanel list of wrapped contents in one column

Tags: vb.net, controls, flowlayoutpanel

I'm struggling to figure out how do I make a flow layout panel that has strictly just one column and upon scrolling it adds the controls at the bottom of that column and not make a new column and so on while having it wrap the controls. I can get that If `wrapcontents = false`. For some reason in my case the scroll bar appears horizontally at the bottom and not vertically at the right side.

How do you make it as explained?

Comment: Have you looked at a `TableLayoutPanel`?

Comment: Will do now, thanks for the suggestion)

Comment: How can it wrap the controls while having strictly one column? That seems to be a contradiction. If the controls are wrapped then that means either all in one row until that row is full and then start another row or else all in one column until that column is full and then start another column. The `FlowDirection` property controls the direction in which child controls are added and the `WrapContents` property controls whether they wrap when a row or column is filled.

Comment: I need it to be 1 column but it makes multiple. How can a column be ever filled in a flowlayoutpanel? Isn't it supposed to be infinite? And it is infinite if I turn off the content wrapping

Comment: *"How can a column be ever filled in a flowlayoutpanel?"*. Is a `FlowLayoutPanel` infinitely tall? No, it has a specific `Height`, like every other control. When the child controls reach that height, the next one wraps. That's how wrapping works. Have you never used word wrap in Notepad? The document window has a set width and the text can wrap at that width or not. Either you want the controls to wrap or you don't. You choose the one you want using the `WrapContents` property. I'm still not seeing the problem.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating further) The problem is that I need a 1 column list that could go on infinitely and that the controls are not cropped but wrapped at the top and bottom... like a contacts list on the phone, you know?

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you want the user to be able to scroll down to the bottom of the list and the automatically start again at the first add though is a dial? If so then that's not how the FlowLayoutPanel sent standard control works. If not then I have no idea what you are saying.

Comment: *"For some reason in my case the scroll bar appears horizontally at the bottom and not vertically at the right side"*. That sounds like you need to set the Flow Direction property, which you should already know from reading the documentation for that control.

Comment: It is set properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251494/discussion-between-eduards-and-jmcilhinney).